# How do I import a csv into R in such a way that it recognises it as a 3D array?

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, import

I am trying to run a multi species occupancy model in R, using ths spOccupancy package. I have run single species occupancy models using this package, but now I want to run multi-species occupancy models to see how species interact to influence their occupancy over a landscape. However, this requires me to turn the first element of my list, y, into a 3D array, where the first dimension is equal to the number of species, second dimension equal to the number of sites, and third dimension equal to the maximum number of replicates at a given site. At the moment I have a CSV file where the first column is the name of the site, the next column is the name of the species, and the next several columns is 0s and 1s, depending on whether the species was detected. How do I turn this into a 3D array to run the multi-species occupancy model?

This is what the first five rows of the input looks like at the moment:

```
structure(list(Site = c("Piata", "Piata", "Piata", "Piata", "Piata"
), Species = c("Anas_flavirostris", "Anas_georgica", "Chloephaga_melanoptera", 
"Chroicocephalus_serranus", "Fulica_ardesiaca"), Y.1 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Y.2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Y.3 = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is an example of the output which I think is needed

```
Y
, , Site = Piata

                          Rep
Species                        Y1     Y2     Y3
  Anas_flavirostris            1      0      1
  Anas_georgica                0      1      0
  Chloephaga_melanoptera       1      1      1
  Chroicocephalus_serranus     1      0      0
  Fulica_ardesiaca             1      1      1

, , Site = Chimu

                           Rep
Species                        Y1     Y2     Y3
  Anas_flavirostris            0      0      NA
  Anas_georgica                1      1      NA
  Chloephaga_melanoptera       1      0      NA
  Chroicocephalus_serranus     0      1      NA
  Fulica_ardesiaca             1      1      NA

, , Site = Huata

                         Rep
Species                        Y1     Y2     Y3
  Anas_flavirostris            1      1      0
  Anas_georgica                0      0      0
  Chloephaga_melanoptera       0      0      1
  Chroicocephalus_serranus     1      1      1
  Fulica_ardesiaca             1      1      1
```

I should add that I tried to make this output as follows:

I create a csv which just had the presence/absence columns (Y1, Y2, Y3) and then tried:

```
DataArray <- array(c(CountDataPresence), dim = c(61,3,93))
```

For 61 species, 3 repeated counts maximum per site, and 93 sites. An example of what I got is this:

```
, , 1

     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186
[2,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186

, , 2

     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186
[2,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186

, , 3

     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186
[2,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186

, , 4

     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186
[2,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186

, , 5

     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186
[2,] integer,186 integer,186 integer,186
```

I have no clue how to explain how this happened, and if anyone has an idea/ knows how to solve it, that would be much appreciated.

As requested, here is an example of the data as I have it with multiple sites:

```
structure(list(Site = c("Piata", "Piata", "Piata", "Piata", "Piata", 
"Huata", "Huata", "Huata", "Huata", "Huata"), Species = c("Anas_flavirostris", 
"Anas_georgica", "Chloephaga_melanoptera", "Chroicocephalus_serranus", 
"Fulica_ardesiaca", "Anas_flavirostris", "Anas_georgica", "Chloephaga_melanoptera", 
"Chroicocephalus_serranus", "Fulica_ardesiaca"), Y1 = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Y2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Y3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Additionally when I try to run the code which works for one site as shown in the answers below for multiple sites, as follows:

```
df <- pivot_longer(MyData, 
                   cols= -c(Site, Species), 
                   names_to="rep", 
                   names_prefix="Y.",
                   values_to="Y")
Y <- xtabs(Y~Species+Site+rep, data=df)
```

I get the following output

```
, , rep = 

                          Site
Species                    Chimu Huata Piata
  Anas_flavirostris            2     0     2
  Anas_georgica                0     2     1
  Chloephaga_melanoptera       1     1     3
  Chroicocephalus_serranus     3     1     1
  Fulica_ardesiaca             3     2     3
```

Which I think is wrong, given that it only has one array and contains values which are not 0, 1, or NA. I am unsure what went wrong here

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you imported the CSV into R yet? If not, I'd suggest trying the buit-in `read.csv` function, and any decent introduction to R should have a section on importing data to help you get started.

Comment: If you already have your data in R, it looks like the [spOccupancy question has a tutorial article on formatting raw data for use with occupancy models](https://www.jeffdoser.com/files/spoccupancy-web/articles/dataformatting). Have you read that and made an attempt? If you need help with it, please share a few rows of sample input and show what you've tried. The easiest and nicest way to share sample input is with `dput()`. Use `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` to get copy/pasteable R code to reproduce the first 5 rows of `your_data`.

Comment: I have imported the csv but it imports it as a dataframe, where the site names and species names are columns like any other. I will add the sample input in a moment. Thanks for providing feedback so quickly

Comment: The answer to your title is: "You cannot". CSV files are flat 2-dimensional files containing rows and columns. Importing them usually gives you a data frame. The functions from that package for fitting multi-species occupancy models (`msPGOcc`, etc.) require the `data` argument to be a list with 3 components containing the data necessary for model fitting. You need `y`, a 3-D array as you described, `occ.covs`, and `det.covs`. You'll need to generate these from your data somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able reshape your data frame into an array-looking object with the following two-step code. Assuming your data frame is called `data`:

**Step 1**: reshape to long form:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- pivot_longer(data, 
                   cols= -c(Site, Species), 
                   names_to="rep", 
                   names_prefix="Y",
                   values_to="Y")
```

---

```
> df
# A tibble: 30 × 4

Site  Species                  rep       Y
   <chr> <chr>                    <chr> <int>
 1 Piata Anas_flavirostris        1         1
 2 Piata Anas_flavirostris        2         0
 3 Piata Anas_flavirostris        3         1
 4 Piata Anas_georgica            1         0
 5 Piata Anas_georgica            2         1
 6 Piata Anas_georgica            3         0
 7 Piata Chloephaga_melanoptera   1         1
 8 Piata Chloephaga_melanoptera   2         1
 9 Piata Chloephaga_melanoptera   3         1
10 Piata Chroicocephalus_serranus 1         1
# ℹ 20 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

**Step 2**: Convert to a 3-dimensional array:

```
Y <- xtabs(Y~Species+Site+rep, data=df, addNA = TRUE)
```

---

```
, , rep = 1

                          Site
Species                    Huata Piata
  Anas_flavirostris            0     1
  Anas_georgica                1     0
  Chloephaga_melanoptera       1     1
  Chroicocephalus_serranus     0     1
  Fulica_ardesiaca             1     1

, , rep = 2

                          Site
Species                    Huata Piata
  Anas_flavirostris            0     0
  Anas_georgica                1     1
  Chloephaga_melanoptera       0     1
  Chroicocephalus_serranus     1     0
  Fulica_ardesiaca             1     1

, , rep = 3

                          Site
Species                    Huata Piata
  Anas_flavirostris                  1
  Anas_georgica                      0
  Chloephaga_melanoptera             1
  Chroicocephalus_serranus           0
  Fulica_ardesiaca                   1
```

This is now in a suitable format for the first component (y) of the `data` argument when using functions from the **spOccupancy** package.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Quick question, how would you modify this to separate the data by site, rather than by repeated observation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But it sounds easy to do. If you provide an expected output I can help more..

Comment: No worries, I think I may have understood the formatting requirement of spOccupancy. But essentially how to make it so that each array was one site, each column was a repitition, and each row a species. I will add what the output would look like in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match the help page for the `msPGOcc` function. The first argument of the data argument requires `y` to be a 3-dimensional array with the first two being the species (rows) and site (columns). The third dimension is the replicates. But if you really want reps as the column and site as the third dimension, then I can easily modify the code I gave.

Comment: And can you add the other two sites to your data? That would help me write the code.

Comment: No its alright, I think I misunderstood the tutorial on the help page. I will try to run things using the code you have written, and hopefully will not have any more issues which will require me to return to this website. Thank you again.

Comment: That said, i have added an example with multiple sites

Comment: I have also added the error which I seem to get when I try to run the code but using multiple sites

Comment: You changed the Y variable names in your edit. They used to be "Y.1", "Y.2", "Y.3". If you change them back then the code will work. Or you can keep them like that but change the code: `names_prefix="Y"`.

Comment: Thank you, have fixed. Now the issue I get is that he NAs in the Huata site appear to be converted into 0s. Is there a way to preserve them as NAs?

Comment: Yes - sorry. Just add this: `addNA = TRUE` to the `xtabs` command.

Comment: No need to say sorry, thank you so much!